# Inclusion-exclusion principle for multisets

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics, polynomials, inclusion-exclusion, multisets

Lets say I want to count the number of monic polynomials of degree $d$ in $\mathbb{F}_p[X]$ that have no roots in $\mathbb{F}_p$.
Fix a $1 \leq k \leq d$ and choose $k$ distinct elements of $\mathbb{F}_p$. Since the number of monic polynomials that have these $k$ values as distinct roots in $\mathbb{F}_p$ is simply $p^{d-k}$ and we can choose the $k$ values in $\binom{p}{k}$ ways, we can use the inclusion-exclusion principle to get the number of monic polynomials of degree $d$ in $\mathbb{F}_p[X]$ that have no roots in $\mathbb{F}_p$ as
$$\sum \limits_{k=0}^{d} (-1)^k \binom{p}{k} p^{d-k}$$
This much is well-known.

My question is: why fix $k$ distinct elements of $\mathbb{F}_p$? Lets reinterpret roots as corresponding to linear factors in $\mathbb{F}_p[X]$ so that we can count with multiplicities too. Suppose we choose a multiset of size $k$ comprising the $k$ values we assign as roots (with multiplicity). Then again, the number of monic polynomials that have these $k$ values as roots (or $k$ linear factors corresponding to these roots) in $\mathbb{F}_p$ is simply $p^{d-k}$ and we can choose the $k$ values in $p^{\bar{k}}/k!$ ways. 
Now why can we not apply the inclusion-exclusion principle to get the number of monic polynomials of degree $d$ in $\mathbb{F}_p[X]$ that have no roots in $\mathbb{F}_p$ as
$$\sum \limits_{k=0}^{d} (-1)^k \frac{p^{\bar{k}}}{k!} p^{d-k}$$
The two values do not agree (try $d=4$ for instance), and I know that the second approach is wrong (because the first one is irrefutable).

But why exactly?

UPDATE: On going back to first principles and studying the exact form of the general inclusion-exclusion principle, I see the error of my ways. I now understand the source of the error, and don't need answers. So this question can be closed if others don't find it interesting enough. Sorry and thanks.

Comment: You could write up what you found as an answer and accept it so that the question doesn't remain unanswered. If you don't feel like doing that, it might make sense to delete it.